# Server time never updated for daylight savings. How do I update this?

Tags: linux, date, time, redhat, rhel

So when the clocks went forward a few weeks ago the server time on my redhat linux server never changed. If I run date I get:

```
Tue Apr 14 16:07:18 UTC 2020
```

When the time here in the UK was 17:07.

How do I update this?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's system administration, and it's off topic for StackOverflow.  Note though that UTC doesn't observe daylight savings time so the output is correct.  If you want the current time in the UK try `TZ=Europe/London date`.

Comment: I never realised stack overflow wasn't for sys admin questions. I've had a google and will post to server fault from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update tzdata by running:

```
yum update tzdata
```

If you're on RHEL 7 an additional check is using timedatectl:

```
timedatectl | grep DST
```

Comment: timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London was the correct command but thanks for pointing in the right direction - will mark this as answered